# Black flickering in iOS video: how to analyse?

Tags: ios, video, html5-video

I am looping a video on iOS, every time one "cycle" has finished there is a black screen visible for a very short time.

Apparently it's **not** a missing poster attribute (I've specified that), but the video file itself, because when I'm using [this video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) from htmlschool it works perfectly without any black frames.

My video is a .mp4 H264 encoded. Is there any way or program for me to somehow compare these videos or analyse what is causing the black frame?

**Update:**

These are the settings of the **working** video:
[image]

Those the ones of the **non-working**:
[image]

While there is a difference in some settings, I don't know how to change them/if they're responsible for the black frame.

Comment: I just corrected video codec `H364` to `H264`. Just to be sure: please check if this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a typo.